# Filter selection for a VFD output to minimize reflection that could damage the motor

Tags: filter, inductor, vfd

Im installing a vfd for a submersible pump, i have read long cables causes problem for both the VFD and motor as voltage reflections cause large voltage spikes upto 2x the operating voltage. My cable is fairly long 75meters from the vfd to the motor, and it cant be helped that the cable im going to use is not vfd rated (cant by them anywhere near me, shipping it also triples my cost). The motor is a 2HP 240VAC 60Hz single phase motor.

To fix this a filter must be placed on the input and output of the vfd (or so i have read). I confirm this theory by reading varius vfd installation manuals and including the one i will be using ([GD100-2R2G-SS2-PV page 66 Section A.4 Reactor](https://www.invt.com/uploads/file1/20220622/GD100-PV-Series-VFD-Manual_V1.7.pdf#page=66)). It is stated that if the cable is above 50meters, a output reactor must be used (i would assume a output reactor is the same as a filter?)

Since my model is not in the list of recomended output reactor. I need help choosing what kind of filter should i use. How many stages should i choose? What kind of frequency rating should i choose (motor will be speed controlled from 0 - 60Hz only) ? how much inductance?

will this [Single stage, single phase, 250V 16A DC-400Hz](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/altran-magnetics-llc/AMI-21A-16-1/9748672) filter work?

Comment: A reactor is an inductor, probably a 3 phase type or 3 individual types; to cancel out the extra capacitance due to a longer-than-expected cable.

Comment: The VFD harmonics can also induce currents in the motor's shaft when long cables are used. These cause micro-arcing in the motor bearings and they can fail very quickly. (I've heard of failures in a week of running on a new motor.) You need to address this also with your filter or use at least one insulating bearing on the motor shaft.

Comment: @Transistor I dont think i can modify the motor, as its usually directly attached to the pump, its usually a pump+motor combo. all i can really do is do the best i can with the filter